# wpf combobox displaymember value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
   Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>();

    Dictionary<string, string> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    temp.Add("AAA", "ABC");
    dic.Add("1", temp);
    temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    temp.Add("BBB", "DEF");
    dic.Add("2", temp);
    temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    temp.Add("CCC", "GHI");
    dic.Add("3", temp);

    comboBox.ItemsSource = dic;
    comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
    comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "???";
```

combobox

===============

(collection)

(collection)

(collection)

===============

i want combobox disply

===============

ABC

DEF

GHI

===============

combobox DisplayMemberPath temp Dictionary Value I hope it's marked as a value

Comment: You cannot. A Dictionary can only be accessed by key but your inner dictionaries' keys are all different.

Comment: You may set an ItemTemplate with a TextBlock that binds to the inner Dictionary with an appropriate Binding Converter.